# Sending Integer Values With AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I don't know javascript very well. I have a LIKE button.

```
<a href="" onClick="begen(<?php echo $post->ID; ?>); return false;">LIKE</a>
```

And,

```
function begen(id)
{
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"begen.php",
        data:"id="+id,
        cache:false
    });
}
```

begen() sending id of post to begen.php as a POST header .

I'm checking it with `is_integer()` in begen.php for security

```
if(!is_integer($_POST["id"]))
    die("It's not an integer");
```

When I test it, begen(3) returning "It's not an integer" . I'm not sure why it's (3) not an integer.

---

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ajax-sending-json-data-with-boolean-value#14737000000976384 :

```
HTTP is a text protocol with no concept of bools or ints, so everything needs to be stringified. The stringification of false is certainly not 0.
```

If everything is a string, how can I be sure that id is really an **id**

Comment: -1: Didn't even bother to look at the documentation for the function, which answers this question right at the top in a large-font note.

Comment: yes you said this in **your answer**

Comment: Yes, and I said it in **my comment**, too.

Comment: Yes, you can also tweet about this :)

Comment: I don't really use Twitter. I might post it to my Facebook wall, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `GET` and `POST` arguments are provided to your script as *strings*. Were you looking for [`is_numeric`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)?

---

Next time, read the documentation before posting here.

- The manual page for `is_integer` says:

  > This function is an alias of: `is_int()`.
- The manual page for `is_int` says:

  > To test if a variable is a number or a numeric string (such as form input, which is always a string), you must use `is_numeric()`.

Comment: For edit : i didn't read PHP documentation , because i think i have problem with JS, not PHP

Comment: Should have read the documentation for _every function involved_, as a very initial debugging step.